# BDD Behat change expected value based on profile

Tags: php, bdd, ui-automation, behat

My Behat feature file is

```
Scenario: verify docs
   Given I'm on "/docs"
   Then I should see "link1" link with href of "https://server1.xyz.com/link1"
   Then I should see "link2" link with href of "https://server1.xyz.com/link2"
   Then I should see "link3" link with href of "https://server1.xyz.com/link3"
   Then I should see "link4" link with href of "https://server1.xyz.com/link4"
   Then I should see "link5" link with href of "https://server1.xyz.com/link5"
```

The expected value for the links changes based on the profile. Say, If I run using server1 profile, then the link I'm expecting for link1 is ""https://server1.xyz.com/link1" and If I want run using server2 profile, then the link for link5 I'm expecting is ""https://server2.xyz.com/link5".

So is it possible to use a parameter file to say
for example

```
profile: server1
linkvar1: "https://server1.xyz.com/link1"
linkvar2: "https://server1.xyz.com/link2"

profile: server2
linkvar1: "https://server2.xyz.com/link1"
linkvar2: "https://server2.xyz.com/link2"
```

and in my feature file

```
Given I'm on "/docs"
Then I should see "link1" link with href of "%linkvar1%"
Then I should see "link2" link with href of "%linkvar2%"
```

Or else suggest how can I achieve in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple option here:

1) Check the link only by the page ( without base url )
 You can have a step like:

```
I should see link that contains "link1"
```

In this step you get the href attribute and you check for the parameter.

2) Get a selector for each link and check what you need (element exists/is visible). You can have use steps like:

```
I should see an "css_selector" element
the "css_selector" element should not be visible
```

Of course the selectors should be based on the href, something like:

```css
[href*='link1']
[href$='link1']
```

See more css selectors here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

3) If you have different number of links then you can add a parameter in behat.yml for each profile, read that parameter and use it in a control structure (if-else, switch). And you can define a step like:

```
the navigation menu should be displayed
```

or

```
the section_name section should be displayed
```

You can define parameters for each profile, but consider using them as efficient as possible, you wouldn't want to have a behat.yml full of parameters.